# PYTHON: ImportError: cannot import name 'ewma'

Tags: python, pandas

I got the following errors when importing ewma from pandas. Any help would be appreciated.

C:\Users\wxie>python

Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> import pandas
>
> print(pandas)
>
> > module 'pandas' from 'C:\Users\wxie\Anaconda3\envs\AI\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py'>
>
> print(pandas.ewma)
>
> > Traceback (most recent call last):
> >
> > File "", line 1, in
> >
> > AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'ewma'
>
> print(pandas.**version**)
>
> > 0.23.1

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Comment: What's your pandas version?

Comment: Either you're using an older version of Pandas that doesn't have the `ewma` submodule, or you have a local file named `pandas.py` that is being imported instead of the "real" pandas module.

Comment: pandas                    0.23.1           py36h830ac7b_0
no local file named: pandas.py

Comment: that's the full error

Comment: Add `import pandas` and then `print(pandas)` and then `print(pandas.__version__)`  to the start of your program, and edit your question to include the output.  This will let us know which of JG's two plausible theories is correct.

Comment: OK. done. please see the updated message

Comment: It looks like you cannot import ewma like that in 0.23, I had 0.19 and the import worked. So I believe they have changed that in a later version.

Comment: I believe in later versions, you need to call the `ewm()` method in dataframes, like `df = DataFrame(...)` then `df.ewm(com=0.5).mean()` something like this. Can you try this and let know?

Comment: that function works for me. Does that mean the windows version is not up-to-date?

Comment: So does it solve your problem if you use it that way? and what do you mean by windows version? It's the version of pandas library.

Comment: yes. please. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

As I have mentioned in my comments; You cannot directly import ewma module in that way in later versions of Pandas. It worked for me in version 0.19, but not in 0.23, which you use.

So what you would want to do is, try something like:

```
df = DataFrame(...)
df.ewm(com=0.5).mean()
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

The following works. Thanks Srimal's comments. 
the original code is:

```
plt.plot(ewma(np.array(rewards_history),span=10), marker='.', label='rewards ewma@10')
```

The version that works is:

```
plt.plot(pandas.DataFrame(np.array(rewards_history)).ewm(span=10).mean(), marker='.', label='rewards ewma@10')
```